# pandas to_datetime formats date from same column in different formats

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I am using pandas to extract two columns(out of many) from a csv file and store it in a new csv file. The issue is, pd.to_datetime formats the date into two different formats. It formats the date as YYYY-MM-DD and YYYY-DD-MM. The date in the original file is in the format DD-MM-YYYY.

Original Data:

**DATE_TIME**
01/1/2016 21:11:19
01/1/2016 21:29:58
01/1/2016 22:49:19
01/1/2016 22:50:41
02/1/2016 00:11:41
02/1/2016 00:19:47
02/1/2016 00:19:48
02/1/2016 00:19:50
02/1/2016 00:19:50

The weird formatted data:

**DATE_TIME**
2016-01-01 21:11:19
2016-01-01 21:29:58
2016-01-01 22:49:19
2016-01-01 22:50:41
2016-02-01 00:11:41
2016-02-01 00:19:47
2016-02-01 00:19:48
2016-02-01 00:19:50
2016-02-01 00:19:50

Note how the date goes from 1st Jan to 1st Feb.

```
series = read_csv("original_sample.csv")
series = series[["DATE_TIME", "REPLY_SIZE"]]
series["DATE_TIME"] = pd.to_datetime(series["DATE_TIME"])
series.to_csv("clean_sample.csv")
```

Why is this happening?

Note: I've edited out the `REPLY_SIZE` for clarity.

Comment: it is probably just the default formatting of `pd.to_datetime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `series["DATE_TIME"] = pd.to_datetime(series["DATE_TIME"], format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%s")`

Comment: Yeah. I did that. It works. But I still don't get it. Is it a bug in pandas datetime?

Comment: Nope. If you do not set the format, it defaults to the result you showed in your question.